What is the physical meaning of BFV action in BFV formalism?
BFV formalism is the Hamiltonian counterpart of the Batalin-Vilkovisky (BV) formalism. Suppose we have a BV field theory
$$
(F, \omega, Q, S)
$$
which satisfies the variational formula with boundary:
$$
\delta S = \iota_Q\omega + \pi^*(\alpha)
$$
we can define BFV theory by:
$$
F^\partial = (F|_{\partial M}) / \ker(\delta \alpha)
\\
\omega^\partial = \delta\alpha
\\
\delta S^\partial = \iota_{Q^\partial}\omega^\partial
$$
Then $S^\partial$ is called the BFV action.
The question is, what is the physical meaning of $S^\partial$?
For example, in (first order) Maxwell theory, we have
$$
S = \int B dA + \frac{1}{2} B\star B + A^+dc
\\
S^\partial = \int c dB
$$
and in (first order) Yang-Mills theory we have
$$
S = \int BF_A + \frac{1}{2}B\star B + \frac{1}{2}\langle c,[c,c]\rangle + A^+(dc+[A,c]) + B^+[B,c]
\\
S^\partial = \int B (dc+[A,c]) + \frac{1}{2}A^+[c,c].
$$
For my guess, I think BFV is equivalent somehow to Hamiltonian BRST introduced in “quantization of gauge system” by Henneaux & Teitelboim and $S^\partial$ corresponds to Hamiltonian BRST operator $Q_{BRST}$.
Pros:

In quantization we quantize $S^\partial$ to $\Omega^\partial$ and then define physical states as $H^0(\Omega^\partial)$. This is the same story that we define physical states as $H^0(Q_{BRST})$ in Hamiltonian BRST.

Cons:

The spaces $F^\partial$ is not the extended phase space $P_{ext}$ in Hamiltonian BRST.
$$
F^\partial = \langle \phi , c, \phi^+, c^+, \dot{\phi}, \dot{c}, \dot{\phi^+} , \dot{c^+}\rangle|_{\partial M} / null
\\
P_{ext} = \langle \phi, c, P_\phi, P_c\rangle|_{\partial M}
$$
where $\phi$ denotes original fields and $c$ the ghost fields. So they are not equal and 2 times larger.


Hi zixuan feng. Consider to give references for clarity. Which page?
